# R - Weights? Proportion? About distribution

Tags: r

Sorry, I don't know how to express the title I want to ask.

Because I don't know what the "keyword" is, I can't find a solution.

my question is

Suppose I have a set of 10000 numbers, and its range is from 0~40000

````
```I use 10 groups as an example.
x <- data.frame(num=c(0,13,58,609,829,2574,6517,12257,16478,19841))
```
````

I hope he can redistribute a new set of numbers to him based on this data.frame number range.

Assuming a maximum of 20000, the range
1~2000=1, 2001~4000=2, 4001~6000=3, 6001~8000=4, 8001~10000=5,...,18001~20000=10

````
```
x <- data.frame(num=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,4,6,8,10))
```
````

Because the real situation is, I don't know what the maximum value is, so I need to find a kit to help.

If my instructions are not clear enough, please let me know

Thank you

Comment: I think some numbers in expected should be different based on your description.  Should the 8 be 9 as the actual value is 16478 and it is wihtin range of 16001-18000

Comment: Thank you, it should be my calculation error.

Comment: Then, the solution i posted below should work

Answer (score 0):

We can use `findInterval`

```
findInterval(x$num, seq(2001, 20000, by = 2000)) + 1
```